# Move object left and right in ARKit session

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

How to move an object left and right in ARKit scene without changing its `Y`-axis, if its in the air then it doesn't change that and just move left and right in screen?

Answer (score 0):

This will be a very general example, I could get more specific if you make your question more detailed or give an example of what you are trying to do.

Lets say you want the object to just move on it's x-axis and you had an object of type SCNNode called selectedObject, you could do something like this

```
selectedObject.position = SCNVector3Make(value, selectedObject.position.y, selectedObject.position.z)
```

In this case, you can provide the value you want for the x axis position while maintaining the position the object has on the y and z axes.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i know that we can move axis along x,y,z direction but to left and right i mean when we drag finger left and right it move left and right as we are seeing it not always its along x axis because we can standing anywhere in ARkit scene view and object is at any position. question is ho to calculate the the which axis between x,z we need to move and how much only want to move it left and right not other direction. hope i explain it properly

Comment: You can implement a pan gesture and use the Began state to see whether you've managed to grab a scnNode or by doing a SCNHitResult hitTest. After that, in the stateChanged you can probably do a new ARFeatureHitTest, get the worldTransform of the result and then set the position of your grabbed object to the result position.

Comment: @Developer have you found any solution ?

Comment: @Developer have you found any solution ?